# Populate object from request in GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I know that I can use django forms, but I'm looking for a native( gae api ) way to populate an object with request'data.

Something like that:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class MyModel(db.Model)
    prop1 = db.StringProperty()
    prop2 = db.StringProperty()
```

and in request handler

```
class Page(webapp.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        mymodel = MyModel(self.request)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way that works for me:

```
mymodel = MyModel(prop1=self.request.get('prop1'))
```

if a have a form with a field like the following

```
<input type="text" name="prop1"  />
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you're generally looking for is a forms library with datastore integration. We used to provide one in the 2.5 runtime, but it's deprecated for 2.7 (and not provided by default) because it has a number of issues. Chief amongst these is that you rarely want your entity to contain only and exactly what the user submitted, and usually want to supply some values yourself. Doing this with most forms libraries is tricky, particularly if you want to transform or otherwise modify a user-provided field.

As tedious as it sounds, I would suggest using a standard forms library like [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/) to process and sanitize your input, and manually create entities from the processed data.